# how to use gsmComm lib to import phonebook data

Tags: c#, dll, gsm, import-contacts

I would like to retrieve the phone book data from SIM using GSMComm lib in C#. (SIM Card is inserted into a USB Modem)

However, I do not know how to use the these methods to retrieve the data:
-FindPhoneEntries()
-ReadPhoneEntries()
-DeletePhoneEntries()
I could not find the according syntax to call these Phonebook method.

Could you could enlighten me on this and thanks for viewing my outstanding issue! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

try this page http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm
there is full documentation - how to manage the phonebook: create, find, delete, read, import and export phonebook entries, get memory status...